# Forms authentication, auto redirect in MVC3 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I'm working on an MVC3 project and i have to add a login mechanism. I have to use the `<authentication>` method. I thought that this would automatically redirect users to the login page? But nothing is happening.

I have this in my `web.config` file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

But my login controller isn't invoked automatically. What do i have to do to make it work the way i want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user will be redirected to the LogOn page if he attempts to access a protected resource (for example a controller action decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute) and he is not authenticated.

If you want to use the `LogOn` action as your start page then you could update your route setup in `Global.asax` in order to provide the default controller and action:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now when a user navigates to `/`  he will automatically be presented with the logon screen.